# Python search code in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, search, count, directory

I need to run a program that goes through a large number of folders, all of which have identical structures, to look at a particular file (`data.js`). I need to find all cases where a particular string appears in `data.js` a number of times that is not a multiple of 5 (5, 10, 15, etc.) and list those folders.

I've written a code in Python to check for this (I'm a bit rusty so there may be errors), but unfortunately I can't get Python to work on my work computer, nor can I access the files from my home computer. Hence I will probably need it in another language (e.g Powershell), but I don't have any experience with that language so am a bit stuck.

```
import os

path = 'C:\Users\simotayl\Desktop\Test folder' # will amend once I've assembled the folders

for subFolders in os.walk(path):
    for subfolder in subFolders:
        data = path + "/" + subfolder + "/static/data.js" # path to relevant file
        f = open( data, 'r' )
        fc = f.read()
        qcount = fc.count('question_text')
        if qcount%5 !=0:
            print subfolder
        f.close()
```

Edit: sorry, specified I can't get Python to run on my work computer.

Comment: What library are you talking about? `os` comes with python, so if python is installed in your work computer, `os` would also be there.

Comment: What's your *actual question*? If you're referring to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31207931/3001761) note that you should have **edited it** rather than ask a new one, but at this stage I'd suggest just deleting the old one.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete the old one before restating it. The problem is that I can't get Python running on my work computer (stupid admin issues). I figured it could be amended to work in a different language but my coding knowledge is quite limited (it most definitely isn't my day job)

Comment: This isn't a code translation service. If you want help getting Python to run that *might* be on-topic, but would require much more information - see [ask]

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what your question is here. Do you want to get Python to run on your computer? Fix an issue with your Python code? Rewrite it in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a code in Poweshell that should do as your python code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\simotayl\Desktop\Test folder" -Recurse -Filter "data.js"
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $results = Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "question_text"
    If ($results.length%5 -eq 0)
    {
        $file.DirectoryName
    }
}
```